# parallel randomForest with different results using doSNOW

Tags: linux, r, foreach, parallel-processing, random-forest

I thought I found a way to make a reproducible `foreach` loop with `doSNOW` with the following code

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)
ncores <- 2
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

foreach(i=1:ncores) %dopar% {
  set.seed(i)
  rnorm(1)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Because I used a seed inside the foreach loop, I always get the same results (independent from the computer/OS), namely

```
[[1]]
[1] -0.6264538

[[2]]
[1] -0.8969145
```

But if I use the randomForest function, I get different results depending on the OS:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
ncores <- 2
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
nr <- 1000
x <- matrix(runif(100000), nr)
y <- gl(4, nr/4)

trainX <- x[1:800,]
trainY <- y[1:800]

testX <- x[801:nrow(x),]
testY <- y[801:length(y)]

rf <- foreach(i=1:ncores, ntree=rep(100, ncores), .packages='randomForest', .combine=combine) %dopar% {
  set.seed(i)
  randomForest(trainX, trainY, ntree=ntree)
}
stopCluster(cl)

pred <- predict(rf, new=testX)
```

Each windows computer (I have tried 2 windows computers) with

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

gave me the following output

```
table(pred)
 1  2  3  4 
60 68 72  0
```

Running the same code on a linux computer (I have tried 2 linux computers) with

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

gave me the following output

```
table(pred)
 1  2  3  4 
69 58 73  0
```

I used a seed inside the foreach loop, so I thought it should give me the same results, but it gives me only the same results for computers with the same OS.
Why does this happen only with `randomForest` and not with `rnorm`? 
Can I do something using `doSNOW` to get the same results between windows and linux computers? 
I know that using `doRNG` is better, but I would like to get the same results with `doSNOW`, if it is possible...

Comment: Since the versions of R are different, the versions of randomForest (or some other package) may also be different and could use the stream of random numbers in a slightly different way, leading to different results.

Comment: Do you get the same results on Windows and Linux when running the same problem sequentially?

Comment: The source of the difference does not seem to be the operating system, but whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd you are right, thank you this information helps me a lot! How does this come from?